# How to get gallery responsive when image is in a script nd not in the <body>

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

I want to get this gallery responsive, but I don'nt know how, because the images are in a script and are not in the body.The gallery should never be less than two rows and two columns.
My intention is that only a part of the gallery shows until it gets clicked on.
When it's clicked on it reveals the rest of the image.
This is my code so far

````
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>
   
.grid-container {
  margin: auto;
  max-height: 600px;
  max-width: 1400px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  position: relative;

}
   
   .little-finger-klein {
    height: 300px;
    width:  700px;
    background: url('https://un-aesthetic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/little-finger-klein.png') no-repeat;
    }

   .little-finger-gross {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 600px;
    width: 1400px;
    background: url('https://un-aesthetic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/little-finger-ganz.png') no-repeat;
    
   }

   .justate-klein {  
    height: 300px;
    width:  700px;
    background: url('https://un-aesthetic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/just-ate-klein.png') no-repeat;

   }

   .justate-gross {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 600px;
    width: 1400px;
    background: url('https://un-aesthetic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/just-ate-ganz.png') no-repeat;

   }

   .socket-klein {
   height: 300px;
   width:  700px;
   background: url('https://un-aesthetic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/socket-klein.png') no-repeat;
   }

   .socket-gross {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
   height: 600px;
   width: 1400px;
   background: url('https://un-aesthetic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/socket-ganz.png') no-repeat;
   }

   .pitschi-klein {
    height: 300px;
    width:  700px;
   background: url('https://un-aesthetic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/pitschi-klein.png') no-repeat;
   }

   .pitschi-gross {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
   height: 600px;
   width: 1400px;
   background: url('https://un-aesthetic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/pitschi-ganz.png') no-repeat;
   }

</style>
  <title>Gallery</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="grid-container">
  <div class="column">
    <div id="littlefingerklein" class="little-finger-klein"></div>
    <div id="socketklein" class="socket-klein"></div> 
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div id="justateklein" class="justate-klein"></div>
    <div id="pitschiklein" class="pitschi-klein"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <script>
  var light = document.getElementById('littlefingerklein');

  light.addEventListener('click', function(light){
      light.target.classList.toggle('little-finger-gross');
  })
  
  var light2 = document.getElementById('justateklein');
  
  light2.addEventListener('click', function(light2){
      light2.target.classList.toggle('justate-gross');
  })
  
  var light3 = document.getElementById('socketklein');
  
  light3.addEventListener('click', function(light3){
      light3.target.classList.toggle('socket-gross');
  })
  
  var light4 = document.getElementById('pitschiklein');
  
  light4.addEventListener('click', function(light4){
      light4.target.classList.toggle('pitschi-gross');
  })
  
  </script>
</body>
</html>```

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8EHU.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyDFz.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkmMZ.png
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/05w2y.png
````

Comment: When one of the small images is clicked on do you want the complete image to fill the viewport?

Comment: It should just fill the grid conatiner, like it already is, but I dunno what to change to get it responsive, sorry for my english btw

Comment: We can make it responsive but a problem is that your jumper pictures have their background in them, so they might seem rather small on a narrow device. Do you think it might be possible to have the jumpers as pngs with a transparent background then we can put the background in separately and make it narrow to fit if needed?

Comment: Of course, I'll provide them in my post!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was how to make the page responsive. It was already using a grid but some width/height dimensions were expressed in pixels. The basic aspect ratio of the container is 1400/600 and the dimensions 1400px x 600px were set as the maximum width/height of the container.

What I have done here is keep the idea of this maximum container width, but for viewports where one or both of the dimensions is smaller the container will fill the width of the viewport and the height will adjust appropriately.

Note: it would be possible not to have to create the -klein versions of the images and just position the -ganz ones as background. This might save some photoshop or similar work. Also, if each jumper was provided without a background (ie with a transparent background) then the background colors could be put in by the CSS to give a bit more flexibility if you decided something needed to change. And, perhaps more importantly, on smaller devices you could have the jumper taking up most of the space so able to be seen better rather than a lot of background having to be accommodated.

```js
  var light = document.getElementById('littlefingerklein');

  light.addEventListener('click', function(light){
      light.target.classList.toggle('little-finger-gross');
  })
  
  var light2 = document.getElementById('justateklein');
  
  light2.addEventListener('click', function(light2){
      light2.target.classList.toggle('justate-gross');
  })
  
  var light3 = document.getElementById('socketklein');
  
  light3.addEventListener('click', function(light3){
      light3.target.classList.toggle('socket-gross');
  })
  
  var light4 = document.getElementById('pitschiklein');
  
  light4.addEventListener('click', function(light4){
      light4.target.classList.toggle('pitschi-gross');
  })
```

```css
.grid-container {
  margin: auto;
  height: 100vh;
  width: calc(1400vh / 6);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  position: relative;
}

.little-finger-klein, .justate-klein, .socket-klein, .pitschi-klein  {
    height: 50vh;
    width: calc(700vh / 6);
    background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
    background-position: left top;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
    
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 1400/600) {
  .grid-container {
    width: 100vw;
    height: calc(600vw / 14);
    }
    
  .little-finger-klein, .justate-klein, .socket-klein, .pitschi-klein  {
    height: calc(300vw / 14);
    width: 50vw;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1400px) and (min-height: 600px) {
    .grid-container {
    height: 600px;
    width: 1400px;
  }
  
    .little-finger-klein, .justate-klein, .socket-klein, .pitschi-klein  {
    height: 300px;
    width: 700px;
    }
}

    .little-finger-gross, .justate-gross, .socket-gross, .pitschi-gross {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    bakground-color:white;
    }

    .little-finger-klein {
    background-image: url('https://un-aesthetic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/little-finger-klein.png');
    }

   .little-finger-gross {
    background-image: url('https://un-aesthetic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/little-finger-ganz.png');
    
   }

   .justate-klein {
    background-image: url('https://un-aesthetic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/just-ate-klein.png');
   }

   .justate-gross {
    rmargin-left: auto;
    rmargin-right: auto;
    background-image: url('https://un-aesthetic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/just-ate-ganz.png');

   }

   .socket-klein {
   background-image: url('https://un-aesthetic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/socket-klein.png');
   }

   .socket-gross {
   background-image: url('https://un-aesthetic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/socket-ganz.png');
   }

   .pitschi-klein {
    background-image: url('https://un-aesthetic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/pitschi-klein.png');
   }

   .pitschi-gross {
   background-image: url('https://un-aesthetic.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/pitschi-ganz.png');
   }
```

```html
  <div class="grid-container">
  <div class="column">
    <div id="littlefingerklein" class="little-finger-klein"></div>
    <div id="socketklein" class="socket-klein"></div> 
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div id="justateklein" class="justate-klein"></div>
    <div id="pitschiklein" class="pitschi-klein"></div>
  </div>
  </div>
```